# ARM Linux: Why does the linux expect the register r0 to be set to zero

Tags: linux, arm

ARM Linux booting manual says that the register r0 should be zero. Why should the register r0 be zer0?

http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/developer/booting.php

```
CPU register settings
    r0 = 0.
    r1 = machine type number discovered in (3) above.
    r2 = physical address of tagged list in system RAM.
```

I browsed through the arch/arm/kernel/head.S but could not find the reason for that.

Answer (score 2):

Though I can't find any references in the Linux kernel mailing lists or the Linux sources confirming this, I would speculate that the value is being used as an ABI version for future-proofing the ABI.

Future versions of the kernel may wish to modify what arguments are passed in from the boot-loader: perhaps a new argument is needed for some new CPU feature, or one of the existing arguments needs to be slightly tweaked.

This presents a serious problem when a new kernel is booted from an older boot-loader: how does the kernel know what arguments are being passed in? We could try and enforce that new kernels are only ever booted with new boot-loaders, but this would cause quite a few head-aches during the transition period. (Boot-loaders are written by people outside the Linux kernel team; and are also frequently flashed deep into hardware, preventing them from being easily upgraded in some circumstances.)

A better solution is to reserve the register `r0` to be the ABI version. For now, we insist that `r0` is always 0. If the ABI ever changes, `r0` can be bumped up by one. Future kernels could then inspect `r0` to determine what version ABI it is being booted with, and hence how to interpret the values in the other registers.

Answer (score 1):

Consistency and efficiency. Since setting a register to zero is a common operation, and ARM is typically used in constrained environments, there may be an improvement in code density. The instruction encoding for setting a register to an immediate value is longer than setting a register to the value of another register. Whether this makes much of a difference in practice  is another question.

Comment: ARM doesn't have an efficient XOR-with-self operation?

Comment: Still, I am not clear. Could you please explain in detail. A) What difference is it going to make if the register is not set to zero. b) There are 15 registers but why only r0?

Comment: Well, if the code assumes r0 to be zero and it isn't, then the program's behaviour will be undefined. I didn't write the ABI specification. I don't think there's any architectural necessity for it - but once it's established, you are stuck with the convention.

Comment: Brett, Thanks for the answer. Actually, I could not find anywhere(ASFAIK) in the "arch/arm/kernel/head.S" that the register value is checked. Register r1 is checked against the EVM name, but nothing like that for r0. Also, Since it is always zero why can't it be set in the start up code itself.

Comment: It doesn't need to be checked to be depended upon.  If someone writes code that interfaces with yours and expects that R0 is 0, and you make it not 0, there will be problems.   I don't know what you mean by "why can't it be set in the start up code itself".